# Where does Wine install apps in filesystem?

Tags: software-installation, wine, filesystem

In Windows, applications are installed into `Program Files` folder by default. I have recently installed MS Office using Wine.

Where are apps installed with Wine? Can I decide in which folder should they be installed?

Comment: What about the shortcut icon normally 'installed' on the desktop, Windows start menu, or taskbar.  Is there an equivalent of this or do we need to guess what `.exe` to run when we actually want to use the app?

Answer (score 68):

Wine has a root directory `.wine` in your home directory.
The windows-drive letters (e.g.: `C:` `D:` ..) can be mapped with the `winecfg` program.
Depending on what drive letter you installed MS office you find the files somewhere under the `.wine` directory.

most commonly your installation is in `~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)...`

Comment: the `\\` before space in windows file naming in linux escapes the space and is important ..

Comment: In addition to the previous answer, make sure hidden files are shown in your file explorer since .wine folder is hidden by default.

Answer (score 18):

The `Program Files` folder are in `/home/YOUR USERNAME/.wine/`

if the setup program of a application allows you to choose a different folder then u can

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in previous anwsers the default folder is `~/.wine`

If `.wine` folder doesn't exist, it means you need to run `winecfg` first

This script creates `~/.wine/drive_c` folder and shows a option pane from where you should set the Windows version to use (10, 8 and 7).

Now you can download a .exe file and place it in .wine/drive_c/binaries

For example, you can install python with the following command::

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/binaries
wine python-3.10.7-amd64.exe
```

Test if python was installed:

`wine ~/.wine/drive_c/users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe`